# Calling EndCurrentEdit() results in "incorrect syntax error"

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am having a dataview based on a datatable. when i am trying to insert the values into database table, i get an "Incorrect Syntax Error Near =". What could be the reason?
Since this error is an sql based error, should i look for the root of this issue in Data Access Layer only or elsewhere?

Comment: please provide the insert query with the question

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the INSERT command which is being used. Are you setting that explicitly, or is it autogenerated? The exact diagnostics would depend very much on what your data access is - could you give more information on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you inserting a string literal and using " instead of ' ?